# Provide different functionality with subclasses

Tags: c++

I don't know if this title is descriptive enough... but I have no idea what else to call it. What I'm trying to do is the following:

There is a class (lets call it the `AgentClass`) that consumes the functionality of some other class (in this example the `Initializer`). I have different versions of `Initializer` (like ZeroInit, RandomInit, OptimisticInit) that inherit from a common base class.

How would I best implement this system, so that when the 'AgentClass' gets instantiated, I will be able to specify which type of `Initializer` I get? I was thinking of templates... but does this work on the level of classes as typenames? Additionally I think the methods provided by the `Initializer` can be static. How does that affect the implementation?

Here is some code:

```cpp
//base_init.h
class BaseInit
{
public:
  virtual init(double** data) = 0;
}

//zero_init.h
#include "base_init.h"

class ZeroInit : BaseInint
{
  init(double** data) override;
}

//random_init.h
#include "base_init.h"

class RandomInit : BaseInint
{
  init(double** data) override;
}

//agent_class.cpp
#include "base_init.h"
#include "zero_init.h"
#include "random_init.h"

class AgentClass
{
private:
  double** data;
public:
  AgentClass()
  {
    BaseInit* init = new ZeroInit(); // Problem here: ZeroInit is "hard coded". I would like this to be specified as constructor argument or template for AgentClass
    init.init(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: the question is not quite clear. Perhaps if you show some code it will be more clear waht you want to do or what the issue is

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You're right. I hope the edit makes it clearer.

Comment: do you need to decide at runtime or at compile time which derived class to use? Do you need `AgentClass` using different derived classes to be the same or different types? Thats what you need to answer to know if or how you can use templates

Comment: the fact that you are using polymorphism, with a common interface suggests that you decide at runtime what derived class to use. On the other hand it is common that inheritance is used just because, when in fact it isnt needed

Comment: I could manage compile time, but what I really want is runtime. So that rules out templates right? "Do you need AgentClass using different derived classes to be the same or different types?" <-- This part of your questions I don't fully understand.

Comment: Why do you need classes at all? It looks like functions would do fine.

Comment: @molbdnilo You mean implement it in the AgentClass directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking you have two options: Choose at runtime which derived class to use, then you can pass the instance as parameter to the constructor:

```
AgentClass(BaseInit& init)
{
  init.init(data);
}
```

Or select at compile time which derived class to use. When it is ok that eg `AgentClass<RandomInit>` is a different type than `AgentClass<ZeroInit>` then you can make `AgentClass` a class template:

```
template <typename Init>
class AgentClass {
private:
    double** data;
public:
    AgentClass() {
        Init{}.init(data);
    }
}
```

In this case there is no need for `BaseInit`. The different parameters for `Init` can be completely unrelated types, as long as they provide an `init` method. Also in this case `init` can be a static function, so you need not create an instance of `Init`. With inheritance that isnt an option because you cannot override static methods in derived classes.

As mentioned in a comment by molbdnilo, if the `xInit` classes have no state and consist of a single method, then you do not need the classes in the first place. All you need is a function `void(double**)`. You could pass a function pointer to a free function to the constructor for example.

Comment: Ahh now I get why I couldn't use templates when I experimented with them. My AgentClass has different subclasses as well and when I used the template it became a different type! Thanks for clarifying that. Your answer is greatly appreciated. I'm fairly clumsy when it comes to C++ still :-/ I'll stick with the first options, seems to be more in line with what I need.